# Display:block doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm so tired because this problem for a long day.
The code below seems to be so long, but it's not hard to understand what I did in that code.  Hope you can give me a solution.

I have a panel `ID="ASPxPanel2"` with stype set to `display:none`.

After I click on button `New` --> the panel will be displayed.

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

<table>
<tr>
<td>
<dx:ASPxPanel ID="ASPxPanel2" runat="server" Width="700px" Height="150px"  RenderMode="Table"  CssClass="display_none">//set to display:none here
<PanelCollection>
<dx:PanelContent ID="PanelContent1" runat="server" SupportsDisabledAttribute="True">
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan=4>
    <asp:Label ID="LabelError" runat="server" ForeColor="red" Text="">
     </asp:Label>
</td
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Đối tượng</td>
<td>
    <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="MA_DOI_TUONG" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
        ValueType="System.String">
    </dx:ASPxComboBox>
</td>
<td>Loại</td>
<td >
       <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="MA_LOAI" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
        ValueType="System.String">
    </dx:ASPxComboBox> 
</td>
<td class="style6">
&nbsp;</td>
<td rowspan=5>
    MoreFileUpload
                    <div style="display: "";" id="div0">
                    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload0" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                            Width="180px" Height="16px">
                    </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload0" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                    </div>

                    <div style="display: none;" id="div1">
                    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                            Width="180px" Height="16px">
                    </dx:ASPxTextBox>                    
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                    </div>

                    <div style="display: none;" id="div2">
                    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                            Width="180px" Height="16px">
                    </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload2" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                    </div>   

                     <div style="display: none;" id="div3">
                    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload3" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                            Width="180px" Height="16px">
                    </dx:ASPxTextBox>                    
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload3" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                    </div>

                    <div style="display: none;" id="div4">
                    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload4" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                            Width="180px" Height="16px">
                    </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload4" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: none;" id="div5">
                    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload5" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                            Width="180px" Height="16px">
                    </dx:ASPxTextBox>                    
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload5" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                    </div>

                    <div style="display: none;" id="div6">
                    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload6" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                            Width="180px" Height="16px">
                    </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload6" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: none;" id="div7">
                    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload7" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                            Width="180px" Height="16px">
                    </dx:ASPxTextBox>                    
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload7" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                    </div>

                    <div style="display: none;" id="div8">
                    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload8" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                            Width="180px" Height="16px">
                    </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload8" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: none;" id="div9">
                    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload9" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                            Width="180px" Height="16px">
                    </dx:ASPxTextBox>                    
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload9" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                    </div>

                    <div style="display: none;" id="div10">
                    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload10" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                            Width="180px" Height="16px">
                    </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload10" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: none;" id="div11">
                    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload11" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                            Width="180px" Height="16px">
                    </dx:ASPxTextBox>                    
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload11" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                    </div>

                    <div style="display: none;" id="div12">
                    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload12" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                            Width="180px" Height="16px">
                    </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload12" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: none;" id="div13">
                    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload13" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                            Width="180px" Height="16px">
                    </dx:ASPxTextBox>                    
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload13" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                    </div>

                    <div style="display: none;" id="div14">
                    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload14" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                            Width="180px" Height="16px">
                    </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload14" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: none;" id="div15">
                    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload15" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                            Width="180px" Height="16px">
                    </dx:ASPxTextBox>                    
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload15" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                    </div>

                    <div style="display: none;" id="div16">
                    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload16" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                            Width="180px" Height="16px">
                    </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload16" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: none;" id="div17">
                    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload17" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                            Width="180px" Height="16px">
                    </dx:ASPxTextBox>                    
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload17" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                    </div>

                    <div style="display: none;" id="div18">
                    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload18" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                            Width="180px" Height="16px">
                    </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload18" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: none;" id="div19">
                    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload19" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                            Width="180px" Height="16px">
                    </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload19" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=27 />
                    </div>
                    <div style="text-align: left; width: 263px;" id="divShow">
                        <a id="linkMore" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:ShowHideFileUpload(this.id)">
                            + Add More ...</a></div>

                    <br /><br />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Title</td>
<td class="style5" colspan=3>
    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TITLE" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
        Width="300px" Height="16px" >
    </dx:ASPxTextBox>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Content</td>
<td class="style2" colspan=3>
       <FTB:FreeTextBox id="ftCONTENT" runat="server"
       ToolbarLayout="ParagraphMenu,FontFacesMenu,FontSizesMenu,FontForeColorsMenu,FontForeColorPicker,FontBackColorsMenu,FontBackColorPicker|Bold,Italic,Underline,JustifyLeft,JustifyRight,JustifyCenter,JustifyFull;BulletedList,NumberedList,
       Cut,Copy,Paste,Delete;Undo,Redo,InsertTable,EditTable;InsertTableRowAfter,InsertTableRowBefore,DeleteTableRow;InsertTableColumnAfter,InsertTableColumnBefore,DeleteTableColumn" 
            EditorBorderColorDark="DarkGray" EditorBorderColorLight="DarkGray" 
            Width="100%" GutterBorderColorDark="Gray" GutterBorderColorLight="White" 
            ToolbarStyleConfiguration="Office2000" AutoGenerateToolbarsFromString="True" JavaScriptLocation="InternalResource" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>FileAttach</td>
<td colspan=3>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="PATH" runat="server" 
            size=40 Width="300px"/></td></tr>
<tr align=center>
<td colspan=5 align=center>
        <dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
            style="text-align: center" Text="Thêm" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
            OnClick="btnInsert_Click">
        </dx:ASPxButton>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</dx:PanelContent>
</PanelCollection>
</dx:ASPxPanel> 
   </td></tr>
</dx:ASPxPanel>
</td>
</tr>
</table>  
</asp:Panel>  //end ASPXPanel2 

<table>
       <tr>
      td><dx:ASPxPanel ID="ASPxPanel1" runat="server" Width="200px" RenderMode="Table">

    </dx:ASPxPanel>
   </td>
           <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnNew" runat="server" Text="NEW" OnClick="btnNew_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

In the code behind:

```
 protected void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ASPxPanel2.Attributes.Add("Sytle", "display:block");
//do something more

    }
```

I've added `ASPxPanel2.Attributes.Add("Sytle", "display:block");` when btnNew_Click fired, but the ASPxPanel2 isn't displayed.

Does the `display:block` not work?? Help!!!

UPDATE:

I've found my mistake, typo: "Style" not "Sytle"

But it has a new problem.

There still have a `ASPxPanel1` in my webpage. When I set the `ASPxPanel2` display:block as default, the `Panel1` will be displays below the `Panel2`. But when I set Panel2 display:none and then set it `display:block` again in code behind---> the `Panel2` display cover `Panel1`.

Help!!!

I've updated my code above. Please take a look!

Comment: `"Sytle"` should probably be `"Style"`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem is caused by a typo.

Comment: How long have you been stuck on this? `Sytle` should obviously be `style`

Comment: Display:Block is not a property or setting of aspx or c# but that of the rendered HTML. That means that the function of display:block is down to the browsers implementation of their css/html parser. Unless you are using a very very old version of i.e. I would suggest the problem lies with your code behind.

Comment: thank you all, I'm gonna crazy for my silly mistake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typo

```
ASPxPanel2.Attributes.Add("Sytle", "display:block");
```

Should read

```
ASPxPanel2.Attributes.Add("Style", "display:block");
```

Comment: I was going to post the same thing, good eye!

Comment: poor me, it take me for a long day. I'm gonna crazy for that silly mistake. Thanks you a lot. And sorry for my mistake ^^

Comment: No problem. Don't apologize, we've all been there. Have you tested it now and does it now work?

Comment: yes, I've tested it already, and it worded ^^

Comment: @DeeMac It has a new problem, there still have a GridView below the ASPxPanel in my webpage, when ASPxPanel displayes, it cover the GridView. But when I set ASPxPanel display:block as default, no mistake. Help!!!

Comment: Sounds like you're dealing with some styling issues now. To be honest, this question is about a different topic and your new issue won't get the attention it deserves unless you make a new question and tag it accordingly. Also, please mark my answer as correct if my solution worked. Good luck! I will try my best to help you in the new thread you make.

Comment: I'm waitting out of 9 mins to vote your answer. Because my code above is so long, so I has a little worry to up it again. I've update my code above. Hop you dont mind!

Comment: @DeeMac I've just write a new question, hope you can take a look there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19228529/panel-cover-the-rest-control-when-seted-displayblock