# Panel cover the rest control when setted display:block

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

The code below seems to be so long, but it's not hard to understand what I did in that code.  Hope you can give me a solution.

I have a panel `ID="ASPxPanel2"` with stype set to `display:none`.

After I click on button `New` --> the panel will be displayed.

When I set the `ASPxPanel2` display:block as default, the `Panel1` will be displays below the `Panel2`. But when I set Panel2 display:none and then set it `display:block` again in code behind---> the `Panel2` display cover `Panel1`.

```
    <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <dx:ASPxPanel ID="ASPxPanel2" runat="server" Width="700px" Height="150px"  RenderMode="Table"  CssClass="display_none">//set to display:none here
    <PanelCollection>
    <dx:PanelContent ID="PanelContent1" runat="server" SupportsDisabledAttribute="True">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td colspan=4>
        <asp:Label ID="LabelError" runat="server" ForeColor="red" Text="">
         </asp:Label>
    </td
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Đối tượng</td>
    <td>
        <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="MA_DOI_TUONG" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
            ValueType="System.String">
        </dx:ASPxComboBox>
    </td>
    <td>Loại</td>
    <td >
           <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="MA_LOAI" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
            ValueType="System.String">
        </dx:ASPxComboBox> 
    </td>
    <td class="style6">
    &nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan=5>
        MoreFileUpload
                        <div style="display: "";" id="div0">
                        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload0" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                                Width="180px" Height="16px">
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload0" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                        </div>

                        <div style="display: none;" id="div1">
                        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                                Width="180px" Height="16px">
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>                    
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                        </div>

                        <div style="display: none;" id="div2">
                        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                                Width="180px" Height="16px">
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload2" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                        </div>   

                         <div style="display: none;" id="div3">
                        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload3" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                                Width="180px" Height="16px">
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>                    
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload3" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                        </div>

                        <div style="display: none;" id="div4">
                        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload4" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                                Width="180px" Height="16px">
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload4" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: none;" id="div5">
                        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload5" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                                Width="180px" Height="16px">
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>                    
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload5" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                        </div>

                        <div style="display: none;" id="div6">
                        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload6" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                                Width="180px" Height="16px">
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload6" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: none;" id="div7">
                        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload7" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                                Width="180px" Height="16px">
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>                    
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload7" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                        </div>

                        <div style="display: none;" id="div8">
                        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload8" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                                Width="180px" Height="16px">
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload8" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: none;" id="div9">
                        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload9" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                                Width="180px" Height="16px">
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>                    
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload9" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                        </div>

                        <div style="display: none;" id="div10">
                        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload10" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                                Width="180px" Height="16px">
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload10" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: none;" id="div11">
                        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload11" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                                Width="180px" Height="16px">
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>                    
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload11" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                        </div>

                        <div style="display: none;" id="div12">
                        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload12" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                                Width="180px" Height="16px">
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload12" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: none;" id="div13">
                        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload13" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                                Width="180px" Height="16px">
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>                    
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload13" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                        </div>

                        <div style="display: none;" id="div14">
                        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload14" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                                Width="180px" Height="16px">
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload14" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: none;" id="div15">
                        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload15" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                                Width="180px" Height="16px">
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>                    
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload15" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                        </div>

                        <div style="display: none;" id="div16">
                        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload16" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                                Width="180px" Height="16px">
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload16" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: none;" id="div17">
                        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload17" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                                Width="180px" Height="16px">
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>                    
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload17" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                        </div>

                        <div style="display: none;" id="div18">
                        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload18" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                                Width="180px" Height="16px">
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload18" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=32 />
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: none;" id="div19">
                        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TFileUpload19" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                                Width="180px" Height="16px">
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload19" runat="server" accept="png|jpg" Width="180px" size=27 />
                        </div>
                        <div style="text-align: left; width: 263px;" id="divShow">
                            <a id="linkMore" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:ShowHideFileUpload(this.id)">
                                + Add More ...</a></div>

                        <br /><br />
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td class="style5" colspan=3>
        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TITLE" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
            Width="300px" Height="16px" >
        </dx:ASPxTextBox>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Content</td>
    <td class="style2" colspan=3>
           <FTB:FreeTextBox id="ftCONTENT" runat="server"
           ToolbarLayout="ParagraphMenu,FontFacesMenu,FontSizesMenu,FontForeColorsMenu,FontForeColorPicker,FontBackColorsMenu,FontBackColorPicker|Bold,Italic,Underline,JustifyLeft,JustifyRight,JustifyCenter,JustifyFull;BulletedList,NumberedList,
           Cut,Copy,Paste,Delete;Undo,Redo,InsertTable,EditTable;InsertTableRowAfter,InsertTableRowBefore,DeleteTableRow;InsertTableColumnAfter,InsertTableColumnBefore,DeleteTableColumn" 
                EditorBorderColorDark="DarkGray" EditorBorderColorLight="DarkGray" 
                Width="100%" GutterBorderColorDark="Gray" GutterBorderColorLight="White" 
                ToolbarStyleConfiguration="Office2000" AutoGenerateToolbarsFromString="True" JavaScriptLocation="InternalResource" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>FileAttach</td>
    <td colspan=3>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="PATH" runat="server" 
                size=40 Width="300px"/></td></tr>
    <tr align=center>
    <td colspan=5 align=center>
            <dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                style="text-align: center" Text="Thêm" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                OnClick="btnInsert_Click">
            </dx:ASPxButton>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </dx:PanelContent>
    </PanelCollection>
    </dx:ASPxPanel> 
       </td></tr>
    </dx:ASPxPanel>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>  
    </asp:Panel>  //end ASPXPanel2 

    <table>
           <tr>
          <td>
<dx:ASPxPanel ID="ASPxPanel1" runat="server" Width="200px" RenderMode="Table">

        </dx:ASPxPanel>
       </td>
               <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnNew" runat="server" Text="NEW" OnClick="btnNew_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table> 
</asp:content>
```

In the code behind:

```
 protected void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ASPxPanel2.Attributes.Add("Style", "display:block");
//do something more

    }
```

Help!!!

Comment: I doubt it answers your question, but you're missing the `<`  in the `td>` that wraps your Panel1.

Comment: @RobG oh, i forgot when copy and paste. I've updated

Comment: This is way too much code, and it's too poorly formatted. I wouldn't be surprised if the issue was related to your markup, e.g. an unclosed tag, missing attribute quotes, etc. Please confirm that your markup is valid first, and if the issue persists post only the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You have broken tags. This part:

```
 </dx:aspxpanel>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </dx:ASPxPanel>
</td>
</tr>
    </table>
    </asp:Panel>  //end ASPXPanel2
```

Should be:

```
                </dx:aspxpanel>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```